# PhoneGap loading although script is running

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, loading

I am developing a reasonably large application on PhoneGap version 2.8 for Android. The issue that I can't seem to fix or even understand why it is happening is described as follows. When I start the application, initially a white screen is shown, which is completely fine since I undestand that it takes a moment or two to launch cordova. I have added a plugin to the project that puts the application to the background when user clicks "back" button in the "home" view. I can see that my app is still running in the task manager which is all fine and dandy. If I click on the app to bring it to foreground, app returns to foreground but views blank white screen for ~3 seconds, after which my view is rendered. I am wondering if there is any way I could speed up whatever the process is going on. I have noticed that it doesn't happen if my app isn't installed with APK but is run by IDE in debug mode (in which case it runs instantly just like any other normal app), but it still persists, if I click on the app icon in the apps menu.

I know that onDeviceReady event is fired way before the blank screen is gone. I know that some html is added into DOM tree. By the time white screen disappears even my ajax request is back with more data to be displayed on the screen. I know that whatever is, that effect is not because of my scripts being loaded in. 
I suspect that this is effect is due to Phonegap taking a moment to restore it's Activity, or WebView to restore (if that makes sense).

I have tested that on different physical devices (Galaxy S2 and S3, HTC One X). 
There is alot of optimization still to be done (memory is leaking somewhere, and there seems to be alot of performance issues with older phones eg. HTC One V).

I have tried to show Splashscreen while the white screen is up, but it is hard to estimate, when i should hide it (javascript seems to be running asynchroniously in relation to white screen).

Perhaps anyone would be kind enough to explain what is causing the white screen to be present and what could be done to resolve that issue.

Much obliged, 
Erich

Comment: You can set the splash screen to show for a large time such that it is larger than the highest load time on the slowest device and then remove the splash screen from the javascript once you reach on device ready

Comment: That won't help, like I said, screen is white although html should be shown, javascript is already running and onDeviceReady is triggered.